# Hide field in managed package

Tags: managed-package, fields

What is a good method for hiding fields in a managed package? These fields are used for debugging REST responses, and I would only like end users to see them if they are having a problem. I set security permissions and pagelayouts before creating the package, but they appear in the development org i am using to test the full package. I don't want to delete them, just hide them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help, but what about creating a protected custom setting? This type of custom settings are not visible for end user, but you can control them in the code.

You can create a field in the custom setting and set it to false. So having this value, false, your field would be hidden. If there is an issue, your code can set the value to true and then the field would be visible for your end user.

Find more information about custom settings [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_define.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: I suppose that could work, though it seems a bit heavy handed just to hide a field

Answer (score 0):

I removed the fields from the page layout for the object again and re-rolled the package and the changes seem to have stuck this time. Marking a field as hidden through permission sets does not seem to 'hide' a field from a client organization.